# How to setup a Hp Laserjet 4100n Printer?

Tags: 11.10, printing

Hello everyone I'm trying to setup my hp laserjet 4100n printer, but ubuntu 11.10 doesn't recognize it.

I try to install the HPLIP or linux drivers, but then when it says to restart your computer when you have a parallel port printer nothing happens once you restart it. I try the installation 3 times ignoring the step where it says to restart, but then it says your printer is not recognize please help.

I'm using a parallel to usb converter and I know it works because I try it in windows and the printer works like a charm.Please Help anyone?

- I also try installing it in my sisters ubuntu 11.04 and it recognize it and prints.
- Also when I share the printer in my sister computers it works on mine like a network printer,but it has to be connected to my sisters computer in order for me to print.
- I also forgot to mention that I have another printer connected to this computer, I try deleting and disconnecting my other printer, but it still doesn't detect my laserjet 4100n.

This is what I get and the printer is connected

```
note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.


INSTALLATION MODE
-----------------
Automatic mode will install the full HPLIP solution with the most common options.
Custom mode allows you to choose installation options to fit specific requirements.

Please choose the installation mode (a=automatic*, c=custom, q=quit) : a

Initializing. Please wait...


INTRODUCTION
------------
This installer will install HPLIP version 3.11.10 on your computer.
Please close any running package management systems now (YaST, Adept, Synaptic, Up2date, etc).


DISTRO/OS CONFIRMATION
----------------------
Distro appears to be Ubuntu 11.10.

Is "Ubuntu 11.10" your correct distro/OS and version (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y


ENTER USER PASSWORD
-------------------
Please enter the user (jab)'s password: 
Password accepted


INSTALLATION NOTES
------------------
Enable the universe/multiverse repositories. Also be sure you are using the Ubuntu "Main" Repositories. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for more information.  Disable the CD-ROM/DVD source if you do not have the Ubuntu installation media inserted in the drive.  During the install process you will be added to the lp and lpadmin group, please quit the installer before the setup stage, log out, log back in, and run hp-setup to complete the install.

Please read the installation notes. Press <enter> to continue or 'q' to quit: 


RUNNING PRE-INSTALL COMMANDS
----------------------------
OK


CHECKING FOR NETWORK CONNECTION
-------------------------------
Network connection present.


RUNNING PRE-PACKAGE COMMANDS
----------------------------
sudo dpkg --configure -a (Pre-depend step 1)
sudo apt-get install --yes --force-yes -f (Pre-depend step 2)
sudo apt-get update (Pre-depend step 3)
OK


DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION
----------------------------------
warning: A previous install of HPLIP is installed and/or running.
sudo apt-get remove --assume-yes hplip hpijs hplip-cups hplip-data libhpmud0 foomatic-db-hpijs (Removing old HPLIP version)
warning: HPLIP removal failed. The previous install may have been installed using a tarball or this installer.
warning: Continuing to run installer - this installation should overwrite the previous one.


RUNNING POST-PACKAGE COMMANDS
-----------------------------
OK


RE-CHECKING DEPENDENCIES
------------------------
OK


PRE-BUILD COMMANDS
------------------
OK


BUILD AND INSTALL
-----------------
Running './configure --with-hpppddir=/usr/share/ppd/HP --libdir=/usr/lib64 --prefix=/usr --enable-udev-acl-rules --enable-qt4 --enable-doc-build --disable-cups-ppd-install --disable-foomatic-drv-install --disable-foomatic-ppd-install --disable-hpijs-install --disable-policykit --enable-cups-drv-install --enable-hpcups-install --enable-network-build --enable-dbus-build --enable-scan-build --enable-fax-build'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Command completed successfully.

Running 'make clean'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Command completed successfully.

Running 'make'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Command completed successfully.

Running 'sudo make install'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Command completed successfully.


Build complete.


POST-BUILD COMMANDS
-------------------
sudo /usr/sbin/usermod -a -Glp,lpadmin jab (Post-build step 1)


CLOSE HP_SYSTRAY
----------------
Sending close message to hp-systray (if it is currently running)...


RESTART OR RE-PLUG IS REQUIRED
------------------------------
If you are installing a USB connected printer, and the printer was plugged in   
when you started this installer, you will need to either restart your PC or     
unplug and re-plug in your printer (USB cable only). If you choose to restart,  
run this command after restarting: hp-setup (Note: If you are using a parallel  
connection, you will have to restart your PC. If you are using network/wireless,
you can ignore and continue).                                                   

Restart or re-plug in your printer (r=restart, p=re-plug in*, i=ignore/continue, q=quit) : p
Please unplug and re-plugin your printer now.  Press <enter> to continue or 'q' to quit: 


PRINTER SETUP
-------------
Please make sure your printer is connected and powered on at this time.
error: hp-setup failed. Please run hp-setup manually.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this link. It's the HP linux driver for your printer.

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=29118&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=83436&swLang=8&swEnvOID=2020

Comment: I try that already is what I mention on the top post. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

According to HP the LaserJet 4100n only has a parallel port or network connection. You response at the end of the installer was "p", indicating that you unplugged and repluged the printer which is only applicable to USB connections.

If you are connected via the parallel port, the hp installer no longer enables parallel port support. You will need to configure the install manually. See the following web page: [Print, Scan and Fax Drivers for Linux - hplip | HP Developers](http://hplipopensource.com/node/217)

If you are connected via the network, per the instructions can ignore/continue at this point and there may be issues with the install elsewhere.